# How to use multi-threading and multiprocessing to read a frames, encode and sent in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, image-processing, multiprocessing

I'm using OpenCV to process 2 videos. I have to read frames from these videos, JSON encodes it and sent it using python Kafka producer to two different Kafka topics at the same time. So far I have used the threading module to read frames. Since there is encoding is happening I don't know how to use multiprocessing there. How to use multithreading and multiprocessing to optimize this?

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2, time
from multiprocessing import Process


class VideoStreamWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, src=0):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        self.producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='ip address',
                            value_serializer=lambda m: dumps(m).encode('utf-8'))
        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()
            time.sleep(.01)

    def show_frame(self,cam):
        # Display frames in main program
        cv2.imshow(cam, self.frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            self.capture.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)
    def image_producer(self,cam,topic):
        #compress_rate=90
        # encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), compress_rate]
        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', self.frame)
        jstr = {"image": base64.b64encode(buffer).decode('ascii')}
        self.producer.send(topic, value=jstr)
        print("Frame sent")
        print(f"{cam}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
video_stream_widget1 = VideoStreamWidget('rtsp://link')
video_stream_widget2 = VideoStreamWidget('rtsp://link')
while True:
    try:
        topic1 = "test"
        p1 = Process(target= video_stream_widget1.image_producer,args=('cam1',topic1))
        p1.start()
        topic2 ="quickstart-events"
        p2 = Process(target= video_stream_widget2.image_producer,args= ('cam2',topic2))
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()

    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Comment: Please provide the code you are using, or a trimmed down version to allow contributors to help you with it.

Comment: Okay. I added the code now.

Comment: As the 2 streams appear to be independent, surely you will get best performance and simplest code by using a separate process for each stream - each with its own, separate GIL. Then write each process multi-threaded to encode the current frame while reading the next in a separate thread.

Comment: @MarkSetchell If you could provide some code that will be very helpful for me as I don't have much expertise in multiprocessing and threading. Also, I don't know how the GIL works.

Comment: Also, you might want to refer to the following link to choose between threading and  multiprocessing in python - https://timber.io/blog/multiprocessing-vs-multithreading-in-python-what-you-need-to-know/

Comment: @AVM12 Posting a block diagram of your application could make it easy for us to solve your problem.

Comment: @GaneshTata I don't have any block diagram. I think you might understand the process from the code itself. The algorithm is: get the video stream using RTSP link, read frames, encode the frames, sent them using Kafka producer. This entire process should be run parallel for the two video streams. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: There is more to it than a simple StackOverflow answer. Have a read here... https://pymotw.com/3/threading/index.html and here... https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/index.html and here... https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @AVM12 I understand that you do not have a block diagram *right now*. The point is to provide enough information with clarity so that people can answer the question effectively. Instead of writing about RTSP Link, readframes etc, a simple diagram can encapsulate all the steps while also allowing others to quickly figure out the solution.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks. I will check them.

Comment: @GaneshTata Okay. I will try to put a diagram.

Comment: You should also measure the performance before you try to improve it with multi-threading or multi-processing. Try to measure 1) time to acquire a frame 2) time to JPEG-encode and JSONify frame 3) time to send frame on network and also check how big a JSON-encoded frame is and how many you want to send per second and compare that with the network's available bandwidth.

Comment: @MarkSetchell okay. Since it's my problem involves both I/O-bound and CPU bound I'm confused with my implementation.

Comment: If it takes 30ms to acquire an image, 1ms to encode it and 30ms to send it, in **very** broad terms you will be ok with threading because only the 1ms of encoding time that each stream needs cannot be overlapped between the 2 streams. If it takes 1ms to acquire the image, 50ms to encode it and 1ms to send it, you would need to consider multiprocessing because your CPU-bound functions (i.e. encoding) will dominate your processing time.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks. That's a great point. Also, I made some changes to the code by reading those docs. Is it correct? While running the code memory and caches are getting filled quickly. Could you figure out what's wrong?